# hide/show элемент

Tags: jquery, инспекция-кода

Помогите переписать красиво код, написал коряво, хочу узнать как можно его написать грамотно.

```
$(".first_Ac").click(function() {
        $(".open1").toggle();
        $(".close1").toggle();
    });

$(".second_Ac").click(function() {
        $(".open2").toggle();
        $(".close2").toggle();
        $(".open1").hide();
        $(".close1").show();
    });

$(".free_Ac").click(function() {
        $(".open3").toggle();
        $(".close3").toggle();
        $(".open1").hide();
        $(".close1").show();
    });

$(".four_Ac").click(function() {
        $(".open4").toggle();
        $(".close4").toggle();
        $(".open1").hide();
        $(".close1").show();
    });

$(".five_Ac").click(function() {
        $(".open5").toggle();
        $(".close5").toggle();
        $(".open1").hide();
        $(".close1").show();
    });
```

Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: хтмл можно увидеть?

Comment: я реализовал аккордион и там большой код хтмл, все классы опен это картинки которые меняются, а элементы по которому кликают это заголовки аккордиона

Comment: не совсем понятно...

Comment: ты можешь менять названия классов? и почему во всех обработчиках кроме одного скрывается open1, close1? почему не скрываются остальные?

Comment: А что тут карявого?

Comment: @darkwoolf, например повторяющийся код